# On editing posts

Tags: discussion, editing, proposed-faq

I’ve just made a quite substantial edit to [an answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/2072/166). I didn’t change any of the content, just the formatting which I found excessive and consequently disruptive.

Now, the original formatting is certainly not recommended. **My question is whether my edit was acceptable** or whether such “trivial” edits are frowned upon here.

In fact, [were it up to me I’d even remove the unnecessary image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92560/1968)<sup>1</sup> but I refrained from this.

I’d like to establish a community guideline / FAQ. **Can we get a consensus on editing other people’s posts?**

For comparison: yes, on other Stack Exchange communities such edits are – generally – encouraged, as long as they don’t destroy the original answer or make it worse (e.g. inaccurate). There is no consensus on the use of decorative images (that I’m aware of).

---

<sup>1)</sup> Especially since it’s probably copyrighted, used without permission, and isn’t covered by fair use.

Comment: @bobthejoe Good point, I made the question more general.

Answer (score 3):

The answer you linked to is of very low quality, so I'd say do whatever you can to salvage it.

Definitely remove decorative images: they add absolutely nothing and encourage more worthless gimmicks.

Personally, I think images in general should be used sparingly, since they have potential to draw attention away from more useful content.

Comment: I think images *can* be very helpful – but then I guess we are not in disagreement. Regarding the quality of the answer, this is actually a pity for the point I was trying to make – what would the policy be if the text were of good quality but the formatting atrocious?

Comment: I've generally operated under the assumption that the poster owns the idea, (and of course the up / down votes) but the phrasing, formatting, etc is treated as part of public domain: if you're fairly sure you can improve it, do it.

Comment: I tend to abuse images since they usually mean a couple thousand words.

Comment: @bobthejoe, I'm bad at reading, so I agree with you to some extent. If the image means a few thousand _relevant_ words, it's far better than the same space filled with text. The issue is more that they are often full of irrelevant information: if you're talking about echolocation, there's a temptation to throw in a photo of a dolphin just, ya know, being a dolphin. It's cute and it will generate up votes, but there's a very good chance it adds nothing to the reader's understanding, and if everyone lazy-pastes a picture of a dolphin in their echolocation answer, it's a lot of  dolphins.